# How to speed up fetching MediaItem with gatsby-source-wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, gatsby

I'm building with Gatsby + WordPress, and the WP media library has 1000+ items; this takes a *very* long time to download during every fresh build:

[image: gatsby-source-wordpress downloading MediaItem]

How can I have gatsby-source-wordpress fetch multiple images simultaneously? It appears that it fetches them sequentially.

My current **gatsby-config.js** options for gatsby-source-wordpress:

```
resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
options: {
  // the only required plugin option for WordPress is the GraphQL url.
  url: process.env.WPGRAPHQL_URL,
  schema: {
    timeout: 30000,
    perPage: 500,
    requestConcurrency: 50,
  },
  type: {
    MediaItem: {
      localFile: {
        requestConcurrency: 200,
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Wondering if this is a frontend tweak needed, or something to adjust server-side.

The `requestConcurrency: 200` setting in `localFile` doesn't appear to affect anything here.

Comment: Did you figured out hot to speed the build?

Comment: @lopandpe unfortunately, no. I haven't used Gatsby much since the time I spent on this project in 2021.